# How to change parameter value in any function in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this function

```
private void fun(String a, String b, String c)
{
}
```

I want to do something like this

```
private void fun(String a, String b, String c)
{
    clean(a, b, c);
    // params clean
}

private void clean(ref params String[] c)
{
    foreach (String t in c)
    {
        t = t.replace("'", " ");
    }
}
```

Of course this not works because a params cannot be ref.

There is a way to do this? I'm goint to use it in many functions, some of them have 10 to 15 parameters.

Thanks,

Comment: it sounds a bit like how observable collections work, have you googled them?

Comment: Could possibly be done in VB.NET using optional parameters. Maybe C#4 has optional parameters also ( I am not sure ). So create a method with 15 optional `ref string` parameters that clean the data.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do this. To be honest, if you've got a method with 10-15 parameters, that sounds like you could use some more encapsulation to start with - and at that point it's a different ballgame, because if you pass in a reference to an instance of a mutable class, your method can change the properties within that instance.

If you could give more concrete details of your use case that would help - it may be that you want to write an extension method on `string`, just for convenience:

```
internal string ReplaceQuotes(this string text)
{
    return text.Replace("'", " ");
}
```

Then you can just refer to `foo.ReplaceQuotes()` when you need to - it won't change the value of `foo`, but it means whatever you pass the return value to will be appropriately trimmed.

Note that if you're doing this to try to avoid SQL injection attacks, it would be a *much* better idea to use parameterized SQL instead. Of course, it may be nothing to do with that :)

Comment: Agree with the SQL injection stuff, if you look at the quotename implementation from EF it isn't as simple as "escape all quotes".

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you want a single magic method to do this, but since that isn't possible, don't discount the simple (but tedious) solution of multiple overloads.

```
public static class Cleaner
{
    public static string Clean(this string s)
    {
        return s.Replace("'", " "); 
    }

    public static void Clean(ref string s1)
    {
        s1 = s1.Clean();
    }

    public static void Clean(ref string s1, ref string s2)
    {
        s1 = s1.Clean();
        s2 = s2.Clean();
    }

    public static void Clean(ref string s1, ref string s2, ref string s3)
    {
        s1 = s1.Clean();
        s2 = s2.Clean();
        s3 = s3.Clean();
    }

    // etc ad nauseum...
}


{
    string a = ...;
    string b = ...;
    string c = ...;

    Cleaner.Clean(ref a, ref b, ref c)
}
```

It's not pretty, but if you *really* want to have this function, this is how you can have it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can go from arguments to an array, but not the other way around. The best you can do still involves some manual assignments.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test("A'1", "B**", "'C'D");
}

static void test(string a, string b, string c)
{
    string[] args = new string[] { a, b, c }; //build array
    args = args.Select((s) => s.Replace("'", " ")).ToArray(); //clean array
    a = args[0]; //assign values from array
    b = args[1];
    c = args[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] s = new string[3];
        s[0] = "a";
        s[1] = "a";
        s[2] = "a";

        clean(s);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) label1.Text += s[i];
    }

    void clean(params String[] c)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<c.Length;i++) c[i] = "b";
    }
```

And the output was: `bbb`

So it seems that you can simply:

A: drop the `ref`.

B: use a `for` instead of `foreach` because `foreach` doesn’t let you assign a value to its iteration variable.